# Error Message Migration Pending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, localhost

I am working though this tutorial http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app

I'm at step 5: Generate a Database Model. After I run $Rails Server, and check the link  [http://localhost:3000/drinks](http://%20http://localhost:3000/drinks) 
I get an error saying Migration Pending

[This is the error message I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9BP2.png)

I'm not sure where to go from here! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development` from the root directory of your rails app?

Comment: It says to resolve the issue run `rails db:migrate`, do you know why? because any change you plan to do through the migrations isn't instantaneously reflected in the database, `rails db:migrate` does it. Did you do it?

Comment: Did you try to run 'rails db:migrate'?

Comment: I did try running both of those but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your content and error image , it says that the migration files which was generated in step 5) due to the scaffold command are yet to be synced with the database.

For that you should run

```
rails db:migrate
```

And then restart the rails server.

**Note**: You can also check if any migration if pending or not by the following command:

```
rails db:migrate:status
```

Comment: When I check the migration status, this is what's returned ...I'm brand new to this so I don't really know what this is telling me.

`database: /Users/emilykieffer/railsbridge/test_app/db/development.sqlite3

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
  down    20180414191600  Create drinks`

Comment: Down means the migration hasn't been ran, in fact, the same as the error you added to the question.

Comment: Okay. I have run `rails db:migrate` is there something else I need to do as well?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed this error underneath my prompt 

`rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `strong' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3::TableDefinition:0x007fd7511573b0>
Did you mean?  string
               String`

What's going on here? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Add your migration file to the question. Most probably is you mispelled string, that'd be like the column data type.

Comment: That answered my question. Didn't realize I had done that earlier in the tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, if Rohan's answer has helped you on your problem, accept his answer.